# how to make slider with input box react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

[Slider With input box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hBez.jpg)

```
const _defaultData = [
    {
      
      percent: 0
    }]

const [data,setData] = useState(_defaultData)

<input type="range" min="0" max="100" defaultValue={data.percent} className="slider" value={data.percent} />
```

i am having a range slider as input and a input number field

```
<input type="number" name="percent" value={data.percent} placeholder={data.percent} onChange={(e) => setData(e.target.value)}/>
```

if the input field is entered as 62 then slider should change to 64 but its not working. the data is storing to the state but it is not changing can any one help me with this react hooks

Answer (score 0):

Because `_defaultData` is an array, to access `percent`, you need to write `data[0].percent` as `data.percent` will return undefined in this instance.

Comment: i am getting this error in console  A component is changing a controlled input of type range to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info

Comment: I think that might be because you’re changing it from its initial type as an array to an integer so choose a type and stick with it and you should be good